# Property 'Login' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular

I had a piece of code and it's working well, but it gives me this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/dashboard/pages/cbisgate-userdash/cbisgate-userdash.component.ts(70,47): error TS2339: Property 'Login' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

This code is:

```
action_User(login) {
    for(let user of this.ActiveUsers) if(user.Login === login) this.ActualUser = login;
    console.log(this.ActualUser);
    if(this.ActualUser) this.loadActualCompletations(this.ActualUser);
  }
```

(70 line)

```
for(let user of this.ActiveUsers) if(user.Login === login) this.ActualUser = login;
```

Also console.log from 71 line shows good value, so program went well through this if. 
ActiveUsers is variable set in this function:

```
getAllUsers() {
    if (this.authService.checkAuthorization()) {
      let subscription = this.databaseService.checkActiveUsersCG().pipe(map(data => { return data.result; })).subscribe(data => {
        if (this.databaseService.checkResponseAuthorization(data)) {
          this.loaded = true;
          this.ActiveUsers = data;
        }
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      });
    }
  }
```

I get users data from database, I need just login (which is 2 digits, like '00', '13' or something). As I said, this code works but gives me an error so sometimes I can't even switch on my Angular server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring your type as a string but you need to declare it as an object which allows accessing the property 'Login'. Strings do not have this property.

For a quick fix with the `ActiveUsers: string[] = new Array()` definition you could instead write `ActiveUsers: any[] = new Array()` which will allow accessing of this property without needing to declare all the type info for the object. This will lose type safety, though, so if that's something you're concerned about you'll want to create an interface or class for your object.

If you need type safety, and you only have the login property on your object, the interface will look like this:

```
interface User {
  Login: string;
}
```

You can then declare the array like this:

```
ActiveUsers: Array<User> = new Array();
```

Comment: So it should work normally? Because it's working well, I've got a value from this user.Login

Comment: Are you explicitly declaring the type of user as a string anywhere in your code? If so it won't work. If not then could you include the console log of the user object so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Declaration is: `ActiveUsers: string[] = new Array();`

Comment: When I do console.log of my user object, it shows up in Browser's console as `{Login: "29"}`, `{Login: "00"}` etc. because it is in loop

Comment: Ok, well, that's part of your problem. You're declaring an array of strings, which by definition will not have the login property. Ideally you should declare the full type info for your object but if you want to test it you can give it the `any` type for now and see if that helps.

Comment: Right, it worked when I changed this `string[]` to `any[]`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent. I'll add that to my answer. I wouldn't advise leaving it like that because you'll lose type safety, but that will work until you create a proper interface/class. As this is working for you please consider marking this as the accepted answer.